# Local extrema of a linear second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

I had a though time working out the following problem, and I was wondering if my reasoning is correct.

**Does the following differential equation have a local minimum, local maximum or neither?**
$$x''+4x'+8x=32t^2$$
$$x(0)>0$$
$$x'(0)=0$$

The general solution to the equation is $$e^{-2t}(c_1cos(2t)+c_2sin(2t))+4t^2-4t+1$$
*Plugging in the first condition yields $x(0)=c_1+1>0 \iff c_1>-1$
$$x'(t)=e^{-2t}(-2c_1sin(2t)+2c_2cos(2t))-2e^{-2t}(c_1cos(2t)+c_2sin(2t))+8t-4$$
$$x'(0)=2c_2-2c_1-4=0$$
Solve for $c_2$ (needed for the second derivative test)
$$2c_2-2c_1-4=0$$
$$2c_2=2c_1+4$$
$$c_2=c_1+2$$
$$x''(t)=8c_1e^{-2t}sin(2t)-8c_2e^{-2t}cos(2t)+8$$
$$x''(0)=-8c_2+8=-8(c_1+2)+8=-8c_1-8$$

Now eiter:

local maximum $\iff x''(0)>0\iff-8c_1-8>0\iff-8c_1>8\iff c_1<-1$ (which is impossible due to *)

local minimum $\iff x''(0)<0\iff-8c_1-8<0\iff-8c_1<8\iff c_1>-1$

So the conclusion is that $x'(t)$ has a local minimum at $t=0$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: $x''+4x'+8x=32t^2  \implies x''(0)=-8x(0)  <0$